# Error 500 when trying to get WADL of jax-rs service

Tags: java, rest, cxf, apache-karaf, wadl

In our project we deployed two JAX-RS services into Karaf container. When I'm trying to get WADL by the service link (http://localhost:8181/cxf/myservice1?_wadl), I got this error:

> Caused by:
>
> javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider
>   org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found   at
>   javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:121)

thought the second service doesn't has such issue and retrieve correct WADl (http://localhost:8181/cxf/myservice2?_wadl):

```
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <grammars/> 
    <resources base="http://localhost:8181/cxf/dictionary">
         <resource path="/">
             <resource path="{name}">
                 <param name="name" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
                 <method name="GET">.....
```

We use CXF 3.1.3.
Both services configured via Blueprint, but in this place all configurations are the same, that is why I don't expect the issue here.

As I understand, in case of CXF, WADL has been generating by default just to append JAX-RS service link with "?_wadl", that means I can't cofigure it manually, isn't it?

I appreciate for any suggestions where I need to look at. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out and want to share with community if someone else will face with such issue.

Turned out that WADL generation needs [Xalan](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) XSLT processor for xml transformation. As CXF doesn't contain that library in feature set it needs to be installed as separate bundle. Also Xalan depends on [Apache Commons BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/), that means the bundle BCEL also needs to be added into Karaf (or any other OSGI container if those are exist at all). In my case a feature excerpt looks like:

```
<bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xalan/2.7.1_7</bundle>
<bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.bcel/5.2_4</bundle>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order for the wadl link to work you need to add the cxf service-description library.

The maven dependency would be:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but in Karaf container I installed CXF as a whole feature, that means all libraries including this one you mentioned, already up and running.

Comment: your suggestion pushed me to dig into other way that I looked before. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Gunnar, By adding this dependency I am able to access ?_wadl URL.